# I Want This Infographics as Animated TikZ in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want this in `TikZ` [image: this picture] where the images in the small circles will be `.jpg` or `.png` image files attached from my working directory.

I also want the `TikZ` animated such that the first `child` will show first, followed by the second then the third and lastly the fourth.

This is what I have tried:

```
    \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{math}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
          \frametitle{Test with Infographics}
            \end{tikzpicture}

            \end{tikzpicture}
          \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Starting point: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/.

Comment: In general, I do *not* think that LaTeX is the right tool for such types of graphics.

Comment: Already having some reputation you should know better, shouldn't you? Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple sketch is presented below. It uses the `style` named `figNode/.style` to insert an image inside a node, so you can control how the outside border will interact with your figure and it also uses somes `foreach`s loops to write a little bit more compact some syntaxes. Other elements were just positioned somewhere to resemble your original concept.

It still needs some improvements with:

- shading,
- better positioning,
- replacing connections between central half circle and the four element blocks, and
- the rectangle-like form with elements.

---

The following MWE is just a starting point.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
  figNode/.style={
    path picture={
      \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {#1};}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
  \node (a) at (60:10){};
  \node (b) at (20:10){};
  \node (c) at (-20:10){};
  \node (d) at (-60:10){};
  
  \foreach \r/\c in {90/blue,45/green,0/red,-45/yellow}{
    \fill[\c!50] (0,0) -- (\r:4) arc (\r:\r-45:4) -- cycle;
  };
  
  \foreach \r/\c/\p in {67.5/blue/a,22.5/green/b,-22.5/red/c,-67.5/yellow/d}{
    \draw[\c] (\r:4) -- (\p);
    \fill[gray!50] (\r:4) circle (0.5);
    \fill[\c] (\r:4) circle (0.25);
  };
  
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (3) node[align=center]{Business \\ infographic};
  
  \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (3.5,7) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
  \draw[fill=blue!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}]
    (a) circle (1);
  \node[right=2 of a, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=blue!50,
    minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 01};
  
  \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (7.8,1.6) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
  \draw[fill=green!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}]
    (b) circle (1);
  \node[right=2 of b, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=green!50,
    minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 02};
  
  \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (8,-5) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
  \draw[fill=red!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}}]
    (c) circle (1);
  \node[right=2 of c, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=red!50,
    minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 03};
  
  \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (3.2,-10.4) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
  \draw[fill=yellow!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}]
    (d) circle (1);
  \node[right=2 of d, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=yellow!50,
    minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 04};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

***Update and animation***

Some time ago I asked a question about [Best method to animate a step by step state space diagram construction in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642435/140133).

Now I can provide a new solution to the original question. I can show now how to create a PDF-embedded animation.

The command `\uncover` was provided by @AlexG and is the key for this technique to work.

The MWE and a gif follow

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[autoplay,controls,loop]{animate}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
  figNode/.style={
    path picture={
      \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {#1};}}
}
% ==== Command used to uncover frames to provide an animated result
\newcommand\uncover[3]{\ifnum#1<#2\phantom{#3}\else#3\fi}
% ==== 
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,poster=last,begin={
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,very thick]
      \useasboundingbox (-3.5,-10.5) rectangle (16,10.5);
    },
    end={\end{tikzpicture}}
  ]{2}
  \multiframe{14}{i=0+1}{
    \node (a) at (60:10){};
    \node (b) at (20:10){};
    \node (c) at (-20:10){};
    \node (d) at (-60:10){};

    \foreach \r/\c/\q in {90/blue/2,45/green/5,0/red/8,-45/yellow/11}{
      \uncover{\i}{\q}{
        \fill[\c!50] (0,0) -- (\r:4) arc (\r:\r-45:4) -- cycle;
      }
    };

    \foreach \r/\c/\p/\q in {67.5/blue/a/3,22.5/green/b/6,-22.5/red/c/9,-67.5/yellow/d/12}{
      \uncover{\i}{\q}{
        \draw[\c] (\r:4) -- (\p);
        \fill[gray!50] (\r:4) circle (0.5);
        \fill[\c] (\r:4) circle (0.25);
      }
    };

    \uncover{\i}{1}{\draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (3) node[align=center]{Business \\ infographic};}

    \uncover{\i}{4}{
      \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (3.5,7) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
      \draw[fill=blue!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-a}}] (a) circle (1);
      \node[right=2 of a, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=blue!50,
      minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 01};
    }

    \uncover{\i}{7}{
      \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (7.8,1.6) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
      \draw[fill=green!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-b}}] (b) circle (1);
      \node[right=2 of b, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=green!50,
      minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 02};
    }

    \uncover{\i}{10}{
      \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (8,-5) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
      \draw[fill=red!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-c}}] (c) circle (1);
      \node[right=2 of c, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=red!50,
      minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 03};
    }

    \uncover{\i}{13}{
      \draw[rounded corners=25pt, fill=gray!50] (3.2,-10.4) rectangle ++(7,3.5);
      \draw[fill=yellow!50, figNode={\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}] (d) circle (1);
      \node[right=2 of d, rounded rectangle=25pt, rounded rectangle west arc=none, draw, fill=yellow!50,
      minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm] {Elemento 04};
    }
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't noticed you also want an animation. I would considere that a separated question.

Comment: great! I will see how to improve on this your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Draw in inkscape, and anitmate use `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[autoplay,controls,loop]{1}{drawing}{1}{22}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have error issues: `Package animate Error: None of the files` and `Unknown graphics extension: .cfg. ...[autoplay,controls,loop]{1}{drawing}{1}{22}`

Comment: Where can I get the graphics you called `drawing` I mean from `1` to `22`?

Comment: I can not reproduce your animation. Your output looks great. For the sake of this large community please make your work reproduciable.

Comment: @DanielJames, the graphics in `drawing` numbered from 1 to 22 are the drawing Tom created with [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and saved in his Hard Disk. Those graphics are loaded and animated as described at `5 The user interface` of [animate manual](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf).

Comment: The `gif` file in the answer can be split into the single frame picture ( e.g. https://ezgif.com/). You can get what you want if you put a little bit effort on it.